# How do I test child processes using chai and mocha?

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, child-process, chai

I'm creating a framework to execute processes at a specific time (cron-like) and to test it I'm using chai-mocha-grunt.

The architecture of solution is based on [this example](https://github.com/zamnuts/nodejs-fork-example). Basically, we have:

- A Master process, which calls the Child (via child_process.fork) a specific number of times.
- A Child process, which executes something using setInverval();
- A process to call the Master.start() function.

With this architecture how do I test to ensure that threads are executed at the correct time using mocha and chai (with the 'assert' library)?

In other words, how do I make chai 'listen' to the threads and check if they are executed at the correct time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you need chai itself to listen to your threads. If you're building off of the example you linked this should be pretty straight forward because the `Master.js` is already an EventEmitter and it's already emitting all events it hears from the child processes.

Your test structure could be as simple as this:

```
describe('ForkExample test', function() {
    // Set an appropriate test timeout here
    this.timeout(1000);

    it('should do stuff at the right time', function(done) {
        var fe = new ForkExample();
        fe.start(1);
        fe.on('event', function(type, pid, e) {
            if (type === 'child message') {
                // Check here that the timing was within some expected range
                done();
            }
        });
    });
});
```